# Не запускается поток

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Пытаюсь запустить поток и в нем запустить mp3.

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")
 
void run() {
  mciSendString("play cl/resurse/voice/test.mp3 wait", NULL, 0, NULL)  ; 
}

int main() {
  std::thread th(run);
  std::cout << "end" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

пытаюсь собрать `g++ -c main.cpp`

выдает ошибку

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:14:21: error: no matching function for call to 'std::thread::thread(void (&)())'
   14 |   std::thread th(run);
      |                     ^
In file included from c:\users\redlava\gcc\include\c++\12.1.0\thread:43,
                 from main.cpp:1:
c:\users\redlava\gcc\include\c++\12.1.0\bits\std_thread.h:156:5: note: candidate: 'std::thread::thread(std::thread&&)'
  156 |     thread(thread&& __t) noexcept
      |     ^~~~~~
c:\users\redlava\gcc\include\c++\12.1.0\bits\std_thread.h:156:21: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void()' to 'std::thread&&'
  156 |     thread(thread&& __t) noexcept
      |            ~~~~~~~~~^~~
c:\users\redlava\gcc\include\c++\12.1.0\bits\std_thread.h:120:5: note: candidate: 'std::thread::thread()'
  120 |     thread() noexcept = default;
      |     ^~~~~~
c:\users\redlava\gcc\include\c++\12.1.0\bits\std_thread.h:120:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

Возможно я среду неправильно настроил или еще что.
P.s. Только начал учить плюсы, не судите строго.

Comment: Попробуйте собрать вот так -- `g++ -o main main.cpp -pthread` (и добавьте `th.join();` в конце main)

Comment: бек th.join(); - все ровно по идее должно собираться, но во время работы будет бить ошибку.
Добавил джоин и изменил аргумент сборки, не помогло =/

Comment: VC++ компилирует без проблем... Впрочем, и GCC тоже: https://ideone.com/Q0CRd6

Comment: Выглядит как битый компилятор? Попробуйте заменить на [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075).

Comment: указывайте используемый компилятор. Еще стоит сказать, что `#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")` - это для vc++.

Comment: Похоже на устаревшую версию стандартной библиотеки. Слишком мало конструкторов перечислено в сообщении об ошибке..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему у вас битый компилятор. Скорее всего вы просто скачали какой-то установщик с неизвестного сайта. Удалите ваш компилятор и сделайте всё как сказано здесь: [Кляц](https://metanit.com/cpp/tutorial/1.2.php). Не забудьте удалить старый путь к компилятору из Path и заменить его новым!

Comment: Так себе ответ. Сам компилятор явно не причём. Скорее всего, проблема была с неверной установкой стандартной библиотеки. Кроме того, ругая один неизвестный сайт, вы ссылаетесь на другой неизвестный сайт вместо их официального - https://www.msys2.org/

Comment: Ссылка на том сайте ведёт на msys2.org. И автору помог мой ответ. @mymedia